# Write Query that check if index is Non-Unique and send an alert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server 2008R2 on user database, there is an index only in one table that randomly changes from unique index to non-unique. I want get an alert every time it happens. what is the better way to do that?

Comment: please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you mean if it failed? If you attempt to create a `UNIQUE INDEX` and it fails due to non-unique values you can't retroactively find out if it was attempted. You can find out what objects have unique indexes from the `sys` tables. I suggest having a go yourself and posting your attempts.

Comment: See the answers here: [Get the list of unique constraints and indexes in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11941305/1220550)

Comment: you could use TRY ...CATCH

Comment: A better question for [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server). I suggest you use a [ddl trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-2017) - which might be a stretch of your abilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can query system table [sys.indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) : column `is_unique` displays `1` if the index is unique, `0` if not.

```
SELECT name, is_unique
FROM sys.indexes
WHERE name = ?
```

NB : for cluster columnstore indexes, `is_unique` is always equals to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT name,
       is_unique
FROM Sys.Indexes
WHERE name = 'indexname'
```

More better

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Sys.Indexes WHERE Name = 'IndexName' AND is_unique = 1)
  BEGIN
    PRINT'Do the job' --The index is not unique, do what you want
  END
    ELSE --You can just remove the else part if you don't need to do anything
      PRINT 'IsUnique, do nothing'
```